# Custom ActionBar setCustomView() has extra margins

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-design

I am not really good when it comes to designing. I already have an `ActionBar` I just want to customize it.

As you can see in the screenshot it is not properly aligned. The yellow one is the default `ActionBar` and the Gray is the customized one. What should I do?

[image]

Here is my `xml` code for the `ActionBar`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@color/grey_700" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate" />
```

And inside my `onCreate()`

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.st_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This ActionBar is out of date, and if you don't have to use ActionBar I recommend you use toolbar.You can have a look at the official web site, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html